# Visual Studio Code: How to make a snippet for inserting <?php ?>

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

In TextMate one could type `php<tab>` to insert `<?php | ?>` (with the | here marking cursor position).

I'm trying to recreate it in VSC like this in the php.json snippets file:

```
"php tag": {
    "prefix": "php",
    "body": [
        "<?php $1 ?>"
    ],
    "description": "Insert <?php ?>"
}
```

The problem is that the snippet doesn't show up unless I'm already inside php tags, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Adding the snippet to the HTML file instead does not help.

Is there any way I can make this work the way I want to?

Comment: You want that to work in an html file, I assume?  I tried putting it into my html.json file (for html snippets) and it works just fine.

Comment: No, I want it to work in .php files, but outside the <?php ?> tags, because that is what I want to insert … but it seems like php snippets only work _inside_ <?php ?> tags, and HTML snippets only work in .html files …

Comment: I see, looks like this bug - which the vscode appears to think was recently fixed - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26275

Comment: I beg to differ … Thanks for the link to the issue, though.

Comment: It's bad practice to mix HTML and PHP. Use a template system and keep the HTML in a different file.

Answer (score 7):

Go to `file > preferences > user snippet` then `select New Global Snippets file` and you are asked to save the `.code-snippets` extension file for the name of the file is free up to you and enter your snippet configuration, for example:

```
"php tag": {
     "prefix": "php",
     "body": [
         "<? php $1 ?>"
     ],
     "description": "Insert <?php ?>"
}
```

And save your file

Answer (score 5):

try adding this to global.code-snippets

```
"PHP tag": {
        "scope": "",
        "prefix": "php",
        "body": [
            "<?php $1 ?>"
        ],
        "description": "Insert php tags"
    }
```